# For what $n$, can we find $n$ positive integers such that $\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{2 a_2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n a_n} = 1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For what $n$, can we always find $n$ positive integers such that $\frac{1}{a_1} + \frac{1}{2 a_2} + \dots + \frac{1}{n a_n} = 1$

I have tried a few numbers, it seems like it works for any $n$.

When $n=1$ we have $a_1 = 1$. When $n=2$ we have $a_1 = 2, a_2 = 1$

But I'm curious how to prove that this exists for all $n$?

Comment: If that's a `contest-math` (I believe you!), could you provide the source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice $a_i = i+1$ for $1\leq i < n$ and $a_n=1$ works (proof by induction is straightforward).

---

The way I came up with it is by noticing $\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b}$ is of the form $\frac{1}{k}$ when $b-a$ divides $ab$ and I wanted the $b$ to be the newer $n$ that we were incorporating, and then I noticed that if $a=n-1$ then it works, and I got lucky I guess.

So the idea was to do an inductive construction, so if you have that $(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ works for $n$ and you can substract $\frac{1}{n}$ from one of the previous fractions so that it is still of the form $\frac{1}{k}$ then you can grow the construction.